# Mobile html shortcuts

Tags: html, mobile, mobile-browser

I'd like to know what are the shortcuts (href codes) that bring up different functionalities on different devices.

e.g.

```
 mailto: (opens the mail clients on a desktop/mobile)
 tel: brings up the "call" option on a phone
```

What are the others ? Is there an "sms:", etc ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that these links depend on the system which they are ran on, and so not all will be implemented on all devices.

However, I found some a link at least for blackberry devices which you will find useful.

Here is a fairly full list:
http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/special-links/

AND
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_link_behaviour_438487_11.jsp

This shows WTAI, tel, dc, cti, mailto, pin as link types.

I know there is also "geo" as one.
I am fairly sure that applications can be used to handle different types of link, so this list is in now way complete.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Android I don't think there's no comprehensive list because each app is capable of adding it's own. Some are certainly more popular than others though.

Comment: I am currently looking at only android and iPhone, but I don't mean native apps. What are the shortcuts from a webpage ? (is what I meant)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite few tricks which are exclusive to mobiles. I actually just published an article yesterday on the very same topic where you can find a list of protocols, tags you can use exclusively for mobile.

Please check http://www.ikozmik.com/html-css-javascript-tricks-for-mobile-websites